# What is the difference in purpose between STAC and OGC services?

Tags: geojson, stac

I am confused about the purpose of the Spatiotemporal Asset Catalog. How does it differ from OGC services which specify accessing data through various services? Is it another service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STAC is a way to catalog data that has spatial and temporal components. A satellite, or aerial, image has spatial parameters but when it was captured is very likely important. Depending on the application of the data, the date and time of the image, and parameters like the sensor and sun azimuths, may be vital. If you don't know *when* it was taken then *where* may not matter at all.
Standard OGC services are responsible for accessing data and not how it is structured at the data source. STAC does seem like it could be a rational datastore backing some services though.

Comment: I have made heavy modifications to my original question as it was not very clear and very broad, hopefully I have improved it without needing to delete it. The missing part of my understanding was the difference between accessing data through a service (i.e. OGC services) vs **structure** of that data provided by STAC. Given that it's the STAC spec... that makes sense. Thank you for helping me understand better!